# What should I do to trim down an ubuntu install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance

I've got a very old laptop (Sempron 2800+ w/ 768MB RAM and SLOW disk).

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04, which seems to work okay (although a bit slow) when I have 1-2 things open.  However, it quickly gets so slow as to be unusable if I open much more than that.

Is there anything non-essential that can be disabled in order to lower the resources being used by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to John T's answer, Xubuntu is a distribution of Ubuntu designed for less powerful computers.  It uses the Xfce window manager.

More info at http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/xubuntu

Comment: This can be done without requiring and entire new distro installation

Comment: Yes.  Good option for people who haven't installed yet, or who don't feel confident mucking around with X.

Comment: To explain John T's comment: Once you have ubuntu installed, you can install the xubuntu-desktop metapackage which will install xfce and everything else you need.  At the login prompt, you'll have the option to login using Gnome or Xfce.

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered using a lightweight window manager on top of `X` as opposed to the full Gnome desktop environment that comes default? This can use a lot less memory.

Most of the *Box variants are very lightweight. BlackBox, OpenBox and FluxBox come to mind. XFCE is also fairly lightweight.

---

The desktop environment that comes with Ubuntu by default is called Gnome, it isn't exactly the best for memory use. Using just a lightweight window manager on top of `X` ([www.X.org](http://x.org)) doesn't have to look bad either, here's a picture of Openbox:

[image: Openbox]

Gnome has a lot of features that you may not need and a lot of eye candy, especially with compiz. If you don't need this I think you'd like a small window manager.

[This guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) will get you up and running with a low memory environment on Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: fvwm2 or xmonad or awesome would be good choices as well.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to almost be recommended already, but I'd say just start with a light weight distro in the first place.

I think crunchbang linux crunchbanglinux [dot] org is a lightweight Ubuntu based distro.

Damn Small Linux (aka DSL) "is a very versatile 50MB mini desktop oriented Linux distribution." damnsmalllinux [DOT] org IIRC

Puppy Linux is also small light weight distro puppylinux [DOT] org/main/index.php

You could also check out http://distrowatch.com/ they have a list of dang near every Linux distro out there, including a brief description and the packages available in the distro.

Comment: crunchbang is a very lean ubuntu based distro.  I think this answer might have gotten more attention if you hadn't mentioned DSL & Puppy.  Fine distros, but they have nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to stick to Ubuntu 11.04, then you can disable some of the services and startup process. For Ex, I run Ubuntu 11.04 on HP Mini and I don't use BlueTooth and therefore I disabled it. I use BUM (Bootup Manager) to enable/disable services and "StartUp Manager" to enable/disable applications at Startup. (1) has the purpose of the different services which are visible in BUM.

(1) - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=89491